# Filtering vertices in OpenGL, with early fragment tests enabled

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have an OpenGL rendering pipeline that needs to check if vertices have NAN values as coordinates, and discard the entire triangle in this case. For this I have a vertex shader like this:

```
#version 460 core

uniform mat3 projection;
layout(location=0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout(location=0) out float outValid;

void main() {
    bool valid = !isnan(inPosition[0]) && !isnan(inPosition[1]) && !isnan(inPosition[2]);
    gl_Position = transformation * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    outValid = (valid ? 1.0 : 0.0);
}
```

If any vertex in a triangle is invalid, the interpolated `outValid` value will no longer be 1.0 inside this triangle (except exactly at the valid corners).
So the fragment shader does:

```
#version 460 core

layout(location=0) in float inValid;
out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    if(inValid != 1.0) discard;
    outColor = ...
}
```

---

Now the fragment shader is more complex, and it needs to read and write into an image. (It does a kind of weighted average blending, in such a way that it cannot be done with GL_BLEND alone, but needs an auxiliary image buffer.)

For this to work, the depth test needs to be done before (not after) the fragment shader, so that fragments which fail the depth test do not write into that auxiliary image buffer. So `early_fragment_tests` is enabled. The shader looks like this:

```
#version 460 core

layout(binding=0, r32f) uniform restrict image2D weightImage;

layout(location=0) in float inValid;
out vec4 outColor;

layout(early_fragment_tests) in;

void main() {
    if(inValid != 1.0) discard;

    float currWeight = ...
    float r = ...
    float g = ...
    float b = ...

    ivec2 pixelCoord = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y);
    float prevWeight = imageLoad(weightImage, pixelCoord).x;
    imageStore(weightImage, pixelCoord, vec4(currWeight + prevWeight));

    float alpha = f(currWeight, prevWeight);
    outColor = vec4(r, g, b, alpha);
}
```

---

The problem with this is that now the `discard` (for invalidated triangles) is also done only after the depth test.
So now these fragments will still go through the depth testing, and if they pass it, may write wrong values into the depth buffer, and cause other fragments to get rejected later.

---

Is there another way to remove triangles from the vertex shader, such that they do not affect the depth buffer even if early_fragment_tests is enabled? It should not cause too much performance loss.

One way seems to be to write gl_Position.z=1, but this doesn't work if other vertices in the triangle are valid and have z values close to 1 (Parts of the triangle may still pass the depth test, even though the entire triangle should be rejected. And since inPosition.x/y may be nan, that triangle might cover a large part of the frame.)

Comment: You could try using a GeometryShader and outputting no triangle if the conditions are met. But I can tell how good the performance will be.

Comment: Did you try rasterizing a triangle with `gl_Position` set to NaN?